# How does pubsub work with nservicebus in regards to exceptions being thrown?

Tags: nservicebus

When using nservicebus, if one of the event handlers throws an exception during pub sub what happens?

1.)  Do all event handlers roll back and rexecute the event EX ( event handler 1 succeeds but event handler 2 throws an exception )?

OR

2.) Do the ones that succeed not execute again and only the event handler that the exception was thrown in?

Answer (score 0):

Events run in their own transaction context.. meaning, only failed events retry for that node (#2)

from my understanding of nServiceBus, a node is a queue which can have multiple handlers for one event, but it will only get one event message for all the handlers in that one node.

if one of these handlers throw an exception, the transaction will roll-back and re-try for all the handlers in the node.